# Empty IMEI Number on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, imei

I'm currently using Erica's code to get hold of the iPhone IMEI number programmatically: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m

This works fine on iPhone 3G and 4, even an iPhone 4 with iOS 5. But when I try it on a iPhone 4S, it returns empty.

Does the code I'm currently using need updating, or is there an alternate method to get the IMEI on the 4S?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, due to fact that Apple is going to be restricting access to unique identifiers like the IMEI and the iPhone unique Id, I resorted to using some code from Georg Kitz which creates a unique identifier based on the MAC address of the phone, hashed using MD5.

Using Georg Kitz's code (https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5), I can simply get the Id as follows:

```
UIDevice * thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
thisDevice.uniqueDeviceIdentifier
```

Comment: Why are you mixing and matching bracket and dot notation? Either use `UIDevice.currentDevice.uniqueDeviceIdentifier` or (preferably) `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier]` -- consistency is key!